# where does a smart contract in ethereum store variable data?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

```
  uint id=123;
  string sname="xyz";
```

*id* and *sname* are initialized.

Where does assigned id and sname get stored in smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

All the information are stored in the **`Main Ethereum Network`** Unless you are not using any other test network e.g. Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby etc.

And Since Main Ethereum Network takes 15 SEC on average for next block to be mined so if you are working on it then you have to wait for that amount of time before you fetch the data back.

Comment: Main Ethereum Network has blocks which stores transactions,means variables are stored as transactions in a block?